# moment generating function question

Tags: moment-generating-functions

I have an assigment that I need to submit, but I having trouble with one of the questions. We just started to learn about moment-generating function and we got this question:

You flipp a fair coin until you get an H n times(not necessarily in a row). X is the number of times we flipped the coin. What is the moment generating function of X?

I wrote Xi as the number of times we flipped the coin until we got H for the i time. So Xi distribute Geo(1/2). Now X = X1+...+Xn . While this is a sum of independent variables.
So Mx(t) = Mx1+..+xn(t) = Mx1(t)+..+Mxn(t) (because they are independent).
Mxi(t) distribute Geo(1/2) so Mxi(t) = (1/2)/1-(1-1/2)*e^t = (1/2)/1-(e^t/2).
So Mx(t) = ((1/2)/1-(e^t/2))^n . But the offical answer from the university is:
((e^t/2)/1-(e^t/2))^n . Then why is my answer wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You took the wrong moment-generating function; note that $\displaystyle M_X(t) = \frac{pe^t}{1-(1-p)e^t}$ for a single geometric variable $X\sim\mathcal{Geo}(p)$.

Comment: @Abezhiko ohh really? So I guess they wrote the wrong equation in the notes. Thank you!

Comment: @Oney Actually it depends on the definition of the geometric law in the first place (see the two columns of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). But in your case, one definition has been given to you in the theory and the other one has been used in the exercise without warning.